# nginx: strange request from localhost in error_log, access_log empty

Tags: linux, nginx, web-server

I have these request to nginx but I don't know what is causing them:

site-ssl.error_log:

```
2017/11/11 05:46:58 [info] 5642#5642: *64 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2017/11/11 08:16:58 [info] 5642#5642: *122 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2017/11/11 08:46:58 [info] 5642#5642: *123 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

What is bothering me, is that there are no corresponding entries in the access_log and the requests are coming from localhost (and at a time I was not using the computer).

I have also checked the access_logs from the other nginx instances, but there aren't any entries there. I only get these errors.

There aren't any proxy_pass settings in configs any more.
What might cause these error_logs (but no entries to access_log)?

Comment: Please attach some more information to your question, because theres many possible explanations. E.g. the output of `nginx -T`, `netstat -tulpen` & your `/etc/hosts` file.

Answer (score 0):

**It is expected behaviour to have no request logged when an SSL handshake fails.**

Access logs log HTTP requests.
If some program attempted to do a SSL handshake with your server, but failed - he couldnt possible have sent you a HTTP request - there was no SSL channel opened to send one through.